# Leave encoding as-is in JSoup when cleaning HTML

Tags: java, jsoup, html-entities

Is it possible to leave encoded characters as encoded when cleaning with JSoup?  For example, currently the HTML entity, number, and symbol for `<` are encoded to `&lt;`.  I've tried changing the `EscapeMode` and even played around with some charSets, but with no luck:

```
Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings();
outputSettings.escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);

assert "&lt; &lt; &lt;" == Jsoup.clean("< &lt; &#60;", "http:example.com", 
    Whitelist.basic(), outputSettings);
```

Based on [this bug](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/372) post, I also tried to create my own cleaner and run the content through there, but that just leaves them decoded:

```
Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(Whitelist.basic());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("< &lt; &#60;");
assert "< < <" == cleaner.clean(doc).text();
```

What I would like is the output to come as it comes in (assuming it's whitelisted):

```
< &lt; &#60;
```

I realize the issues with this, but is it possible, or is JSoup not the right tool in this case?

As a workaround, I know I can replace the strings with some magic value before sending it to JSoup, and then re-encode them later, but this is hacky, unsafe, and seems like poor practice.

Comment: Did you manage to avoid encoding ?

Comment: No, actually. We ended up using a forked version of the library.